# Altair combining multiple data sets

Tags: python, visualization, vega-lite, altair

I just recently found out about **Vega/Vega-Lite** and **Altair** and see it as a genuine contender for best python plotting tool.

The thing I am currently struggling with is to plot information from two data frames into the same chart where one or two axes are shared.

I tried things like :

```
plot1 = alt.Chart(df1).mark_point().encode(x = 'time:T', y = [...])[...]
plot2 = alt.Chart(df2).mark_point().encode(x = 'time:T', y = [...])[...]
```

and that works, but it is quite clunky and not great.

I came across the LayerChart object, but from the documentation it was not quite clear to me how to use it properly to plot multiple data sets.

- Does someone have an example of such a chart?
- What would I need to do to get a dual y-axis?

Comment: some little data for `df1` and `df2` would have made your question complete and allow experimenting on what you asking

Comment: Here is an example of a layered chart from the Altair gallery: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/mean_overlay_over_precipitiation_chart.html, and here is Altair's [LayerChart documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html#layered-charts). If you have any more specific question about layering, feel free to ask!

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I would have liked to add some more data, but since this is a work project this is a big no-no to do.

Comment: But take for example a time series and you also want to plot annotations to specific points which are stored in a separate data frame.

I did read the examples and the documentation and it is quite helpful. But in the gallery I did not see an example of two data sets being used, only different attributes from the same data set. Now on the documentation for  the alt.LayerChart interface there is the keyword *datasets*. I am not sure how I would use it.

Comment: Hi @AJK – you do not have to provide proprietary data, but you will generally get more useful answers on StackOverflow if you can be more specific about what you'd like to do. That might involve creating some small datasets that illustrate the problem you're trying to solve. Read the tips at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make DRYer code by separating the chart logic in a function, then iterate.

**Given**

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


df0 = pd.DataFrame(dict(times=[1, 2, 3], values=[2, 2, 7]))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(times=[2, 3, 5], values=[3, 9, 8]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(times=[3, 6, 8], values=[2, 6, 7]))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(dict(times=[6, 7, 9], values=[3, 2, 5]))
```

**Code**

```
def base_chart(df):
    """Return an Altair chart."""
    # Add lengthy chart arguments here
    base = alt.Chart(
        df,
        width=500,
        height=300,
    ).mark_line(
    ).encode(
        x="times", 
        y="values"
    )
    return base


def layer_charts(dfs, chart_func):
    """Return a layered chart."""

    return alt.layer(*[chart_func(df) for df in dfs])
```

**Demo**

```
layer_charts([df0, df1, df2, df3], base_chart)
```

[image]

Comment: Found this answer after a good hour of head scratching – thank you. I don't suppose you're aware of another way to plot simple straight lines on altair plots? This is functional but slow for a 500 horizontal lines, which is rapid in Bokeh.

Answer (score 5):

Charts with different datasets can be layered together with any of the mechanisms described in the [Altair documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html#layered-charts).

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'times': [1, 2, 3],
    'values': [1, 5, 4],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'times': [2, 3, 4],
    'values': [4, 2, 3],
})

chart1 = alt.Chart(df1).mark_line().encode(x='times', y='values')
chart2 = alt.Chart(df2).mark_line().encode(x='times', y='values')

chart1 + chart2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for that! Could you maybe elaborate what the datasets keyword in the LayerChart controls?

Comment: All top-level chart objects accept a ``datasets`` property that is a key-value mapping of names to datasets that can be referenced in that chart and any of its children using a ``NamedData`` class. But it's more of an advanced feature – not something I'd recommend using directly in 99% of cases.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was concerned with. So I would be able to pass it something like {'data1':dataset1, 'data2':dataset2}.
In subsequent layer charts I would then be able to use notation such as 
alt.Chart(data1).mark_bar().encode([...]) ?
Thanks again for the help, it is really appreciated.
Is there somewhere documentation on creating dynamically updating altair Charts? My current solution with ipywidgets works, but at any update I rebuild the whole graph. In Bokeh the data source was abstract so the data could be manipulated without having to rebuild the graph.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow answer comments are not a great place to ask and answer multiple detailed questions. I'd suggest the altair google group or the vega slack channel.